# Не получается настроить редирект на другой домен

Tags: nginx

Заказчик решил переехать на другой домен, но ссылки на сайте прописаны на старый домен. Чтобы не переписывать тысячи ссылок, решил сделать простой редирект:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name old-domain.com;

    location / {
        if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
            return 444;
        }
        return 301 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

И это работает, если прописать в адресной строке просто домен. Но если попытаться перейти по ссылке `old-domain.com/some-path/`, то будет ошибка:

> Не удалось подтвердить, что это сервер old-domain.com. Его сертификат безопасности относится к new-domain.com. Возможно, сервер настроен неправильно или кто-то пытается перехватить ваши данные.

Как исправить это?

Comment: Очевидно, установить правильный сертификат для old-domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте работу SSL сертификата на новом сервере. Смотрите правильно ли настроены все секции, которые должны работать на 443 порту с включенным ssl.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name new-domain.com
    ....
}
```